# failing to process SSAS Tabular using Snowflake backend through ODBC

Tags: ssas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to process a SSAS Tabular model that connects through ODBC to a Snowflake database and get the following errors

```
OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4) 
      REST request for URL https://ohXXXXX.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=46bd15ee-b045-4ab5-8e56-0c987e28ea24&request_guid=fad00bf2-43bd-4bb8-9280-e4b269cda05d failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=60 msg='SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK' osCode=9 osMsg='Bad file descriptor'.
    
ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (4) 
      REST request for URL https://ohXXXXX.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=46bd15ee-b045-4ab5-8e56-0c987e28ea24&request_guid=fad00bf2-43bd-4bb8-9280-e4b269cda05d failed: CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=60 msg='SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK' osCode=9 osMsg='Bad file descriptor'.
```

It takes a little while for the connection to fail.

Using the same ODBC connection, I am able to load the data into my cube within Analysis Services in Visual Studio.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a device might be intercepting the certificate. Does your company have any proxies, firewalls, security policies?  Anything like Netskope or ZScaler?

There's a function you can run mentioned in the docs that will retrieve the list of hosts that need to be whitelisted in order for Snowflake operations to run smoothly from clients. You can send that list to your network engineering team to whitelist/bypass as needed.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/hostname-whitelist.html

Comment: In both cases, SSAS or Visual Studio is running on my workstation. Why would one work and not the other? Different drivers?

Comment: We have no problem refreshing SSAS cubes from our servers to Snowflake

Comment: Are you testing similar workloads?  Because smaller result sets would go through as it gets the results directly from the server.   You can try testing with the same driver version as well.  But it certainly doesn't hurt to check with your networking team as well as 90% of the time, something intercepting in your environment is the issue (and whether it intercepts all applications, I can't answer that environmental question).

Comment: If you're a bit tech savvy, you can download openssl as well and it will show you the certificate chain.  That sometimes helps me investigate.  You're looking for anything from your company that is intercepting the chain or any errors indicating similar issues.   https://www.openssl.org/

echo QUIT | openssl s_client -connect <account_name>.snowflakecomputing.com:443 -showcerts > certs.txt